# Need clarification on how a "decorator class" work in Python

Tags: python, singleton, python-decorators

I'm learning about how to create *singletons* in Python (please, don't go into why singletons are bad or such, it's not the topic here).

Based on one implementation, I tried doing it like this:

```python
class Singleton(object):
    def __init__(self, klass):
        print "S init"
        self.klass = klass
        self.instance = None
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "S call"
        if self.instance is None:
            self.instance = self.klass(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            self.instance(*args, **kwargs)
        return self.instance

@Singleton
class KlasseA:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print "KA new"
    def __init__(self, s):
        print "KA init"
        self.__init2(s)
    def __call__(self, s=None):
        print "KA call"
        self.__init2(s)
    def __init2(self, s):
        if s: self.s = s

@Singleton
class KlasseB:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print "KB new"
    def __init__(self, s):
        print "KB init"
        self.__init2(s)
    def __call__(self, s=None):
        print "KB call"
        self.__init2(s)
    def __init2(self, s):
        if s: self.s = s
```

Now, testing the above by appending the following lines in the same .py file:

```python
print ""
a = KlasseA('one')
print "a -> ", id(a), a.s
b = KlasseA('two')
print "b -> ", id(b), b.s
print "a -> ", id(a), a.s
c = KlasseA()
print "c -> ", id(c), c.s
print "b -> ", id(b), b.s
print "a -> ", id(a), a.s
d = KlasseB('three')
print "d -> ", id(d), d.s
print "a -> ", id(a), a.s
```

I got the following:

```
S init
S init

S call
KA init
a ->  140525844905496 one
S call
KA call
b ->  140525844905496 two
a ->  140525844905496 two
S call
KA call
c ->  140525844905496 two
b ->  140525844905496 two
a ->  140525844905496 two
S call
KB init
d ->  140525844905568 three
a ->  140525844905496 two
```

So, the singleton decorator indeed works. What I don't understand here:

1. I thought *decorators* redefined the call, so the call `KlasseA()` is effectively a call to `Singleton(KlasseA)()`. Shouldn't this result in a new `Singleton` instance for every `KlasseA()` invocation?
2. I noticed that there were two "S init" lines, most likely because `Singleton()` was invoked during declaration of `KlasseA` and `KlasseB`. Thus, there were two instances of `Singleton` was created. Where were these instances being kept?
3. Is there a possible 'gotcha' with the above Singleton decorator recipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decorators are applied when the class is defined, not when it is instantiated. Regarding your point 1, it's really equivalent to:

```
class KlasseA():
    ...

KlasseA = Singleton(KlasseA)

a = KlasseA()
```

Regarding your point 2, the names `KlasseA` and `KlasseB` are bound to instances of `Singleton`, as shown above.

Regarding point 3, I'm not sure it makes sense to invoke the `__call__` method of the single instance of a class just because you tried to create a new instance. That is, I would think `Singleton.__call__` should simply be

```
def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.instance is None:
        self.instance = self.klass(*arg, **kwargs)
    return self.instance
```

Comment: Aaah, I see! So, it (conceptually) redefines the definition of the class itself, and the instances of the `Singleton` class is bound to the class definition of `KlasseA` and `KlasseB`.

Comment: As for #3, shouldn't the `__call__` be passed to the wrapped class' `__call__` method? If I drop the `else:` clause, the `b = KlasseA('two')` no longer has an effect to the `b.s` property.

Comment: Well, it depends on how you intend your classes to work. Conceptually, `Singleton.__call__` is really filling the roll of `type.__call__` when you write `a = KlasseA()`; it's the function that the determines what it means for the class name to be used like a function. `KlasseA.__call__`, on the other hand, is used to determine what it is like for an *instance* of `KlasseA` to be used like a function: `a()`.

Comment: In your question, it's not clear if `KlasseA` and `KlasseB` "need" to define `__call__`; they are only called because you call them from within `Singleton.__call__`, not because you ever explicitly treat instances of `KlasseA` or `KlasseB` as functions (`a()` or `d()`, for example).

Comment: Another way of looking at it is that `Singleton.__call__` effectively replaces `KlasseA.__new__` and `KlasseB.__new__`, which never get called. (Although, that surprises me; I'm not sure *why* they aren't called, or why `KlasseA.__init__` *is*.)

Comment: Thanks for the exposition. I now have a clearer picture of what's going on 'under the hood', so to speak. My use case was that all attempts at instantiating `KlasseA` should result in the same singleton, but if the constructor is called with different parameters from the first instantiation, internally that will trigger some procedures to 'adapt' to the new parameters. An example: Let's say it's `ServerSession(username,pass)`. A 'naked' call to `ServerSession()` should return the same instance, but a call to `ServerSession(another_user,another_pass)` will trigger a reconnection.